# Javascript function multiple values variable

Tags: javascript, function

I am very new to JavaScript, and can't seem to solve a problem.

I've created a form that looks like this:

```
<form>
<p>
<input type="button" value="CR" ID="CR" onClick= "window.location='http://localhost/test1/html_CR.html'" />
</p>
<input type="button" value="CRI" ID="CRI" onClick= "window.location='http://localhost/test1/html_CR.html'" />
</p>
<input type="button" value="ALL" ID="ALL" onClick= "window.location='http://localhost/test1/html_CR.html'" />
</p>
</form>
```

I would like to create a function `objectType(obj)` that can include those 3 `onClick` events. It should look something like `onClick= objectType(obj)`, where obj can have 3 values: `CR`, `CRI` and `ALL`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The `onclick` event is the same on all three buttons. Is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

```
function objectType(obj) {
    window.location = 'http://localhost/test1/html_' + obj + '.html';
}
```

Together with your html

```
<form>
<p>
<input type="button" value="CR" ID="CR" onClick= "objectType(this.value);" />
</p>
<input type="button" value="CRI" ID="CRI" onClick= "objectType(this.value);" />
</p>
<input type="button" value="ALL" ID="ALL" onClick= "objectType(this.value);" />
</p>
</form>
```

Because I assume you want to re-direct to the URL, which corresponds to the value of each input? :-)

Comment: @AndreiaIzabelaVug Wonderful! And for good measure, as soon as the green tick is available, you should mark this as the `correct answer`. This is so other people with similar problem can relate to it as a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form input").click(function() {
    window.location='http://localhost/test1/html_'+$(this).val()+'.html'
  });
});
```

With this u add the onClickEvent outside of the Element, u dont have to use the onClick in the input Element anymore.

$(this).val() is the value of the clicked input-object

u could give your form an ID so u can make a more accurate selector($("form input")).